# Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'running_time_minutes' at row 34

Tags: mysql, null, int, warnings

I'm getting the error

Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column running_time_minutes' at row 34

with the following script. The error also applies to the column footage_lenght_feet. My .csv has empty values for many cells, but this is because the answer is unknown. I don't understand why even though i've specified 'default NULL' for this column it keeps returning the error.

```
    -- create the Films table

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Films;

    CREATE TABLE Films (

    title varchar (100) NOT NULL,
    alternate_title varchar (50),
    year_of_release varchar (15),   
    Country varchar (20),
    running_time_minutes int (10) default NULL,
    footage_lenght_feet int (10) default NULL,
    FilmStock varchar (10),
    FilmGauge varchar (10),
    BW_color varchar (10),
    notes varchar (255),
    print_publications varchar (255),
    existent_print varchar (255),
    URL_1 varchar (100),
    URL_2 varchar (100),
    URL_3 varchar (100),
    PRIMARY KEY(title),
    FOREIGN KEY(Country) REFERENCES Country (Country),
    FOREIGN KEY(FilmStock) REFERENCES FilmStock (FilmStock),
    FOREIGN KEY(BW_color) REFERENCES BW_color (BW_color),
    FOREIGN KEY(FilmGauge) REFERENCES FilmGauge (FilmGauge));
    ENGINE = INNODB;

    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Films.csv"
    INTO TABLE Films
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: What's in the data? Do you have running time values with a decimal component? Or perhaps the running time is something like '123minutes'.

Comment: no. just integers. the vast majority are blank cells.

Answer (score 3):

You've posted no data, so this is a little speculative, but I assume from your comments that you have an input file something like this:

```
"Title", "Alternate Title", "Year of Release", "Country","Running Time (minutes)", "Footage Length (feet)", "Filmstock","FilmGauge", "BW/Colour", "Notes", "Print Publications", "Existent Print", "URL1", "URL2","URL3"
"A title","","1958","UK","102","38000","","Kodak","70mm","BW","","","","",""
"Another title","","1958","UK",,"38000","","Kodak","70mm","BW","","","","",""
```

(Note that in the second row of data the field corresponding to `running_time_minutes` is empty.)

When MySQL reads this file it parses each row into fields according to the instructions you give it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Films.csv"
    INTO TABLE Films
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Then it attempts to coerce the data into the correct form for the target columns in the table. `varchar` columns require no coercion, so they're easy. Numeric columns need to be coerced to a number before they can be stored.

This works for columns with numeric data (like the string `102`, for example), but when MySQL encounters an empty column it treats this as an **empty string**. This is different from `NULL`, and is not numeric and cannot be coerced into the correct form for the target column. Thus you see the warning.

You need to give MySQL a little help here. Add a list of columns, substituting user variables for the numeric columns you're having trouble with. Then you can give MySQL explicit instructions on what to do with the numeric fields.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "Films.csv"
    INTO TABLE Films
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    -- Put the numeric fields in user variables (names prefixed by @)
    (title, alternate_title, year_of_release, Country, @runningTime,
       @footageLength, FilmStock, Filmgauge, BW_color, notes, 
       print_publications, existent_print, URL_1, URL_2, URL_3
    ) 
    -- Now check for empty strings and set the numeric columns to null if they're found
    set running_time_minutes = if(@runningTime="", null, @runningTime),
        footage_lenght_feet = if(@footageLength="", null, @footageLength)
```